# Assigning Environment Variables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I have a program that makes calls to an internal web API.  However when we're doing development work on the sites we don't want the program to call our production web API but the staging version of the Web API.  What's the best way to do this in rails?

I feel I should be assigning some sort of variable in development.rb and one in production.rb

Thanks

Comment: can you just use `$RAILS_ENV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just add a variable to development.rb and production.rb like:

OUR_API_URL = "http://somepath"

Then you can use OUR_API_URL in your code.

Comment: Important, make sure your value is in quotes.